# How can I make stream builder cart items scrollable by touch?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I created a cart page. I have listed all the orders first then I have listviews under the cart items. But the page is scrollable only by touching the appbar , not by the stream builder cart items.
Code for the Cart page:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:page_transition/page_transition.dart';
import '../../models/user.dart';
import '../../services/managedata.dart';
import '../home/bottom_navbar.dart';

class CartUI extends StatefulWidget {
  const CartUI({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CartUI> createState() => _CartUIState();
}

class _CartUIState extends State<CartUI> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<Userr?>(context, listen: false);
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 40.0,
              ),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        iconSize: 25,
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pushReplacement(
                              context,
                              PageTransition(
                                  child: const BottomNavbar(),
                                  type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeftWithFade));
                        }),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: const [
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 300,
                          child: Text(
                            "Your Cart",
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Proxima',
                              letterSpacing: 1.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: 18.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Column(
                children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('myOrders')
                      .doc(user?.uid)
                      .collection('items')
                      .snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return Center(
                        child: Lottie.asset('assets/animations/delivery.json'),
                      );
                    } else {
                   
                      return ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                                snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                            return Container(
                              height: 120,
                              width: 300,
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Column(
                                    children: [
                                      SizedBox(
                                        width: 200,
                                        child: Text(
                                          documentSnapshot['name'],
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black87,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        documentSnapshot['quantity'].toString(),
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 15,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        'Rs.${documentSnapshot['price'].toString()}',
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black87,
                                          fontSize: 15,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            const SizedBox(
                                              width: 40,
                                            ),
                                            ElevatedButton(
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                if (documentSnapshot['value'] !=
                                                    0.0) {
                                                  setState(() {
                                                    String id =
                                                        documentSnapshot[
                                                            'docid'];
                                                    final user =
                                                        Provider.of<Userr?>(
                                                            context,
                                                            listen: false);
                                                    var postDocRef =
                                                        FirebaseFirestore
                                                            .instance
                                                            .collection(
                                                                'myOrders')
                                                            .doc(user?.uid)
                                                            .collection('items')
                                                            .doc();
                                                    Provider.of<ManageData>(
                                                            context,
                                                            listen: false)
                                                        .UpdateCart(
                                                            context,
                                                            {
                                                              'value':
                                                                  documentSnapshot[
                                                                          'value'] -
                                                                      0.5,
                                                              'price': documentSnapshot[
                                                                      'price'] -
                                                                  (documentSnapshot[
                                                                          'ogprice'] /
                                                                      2),
                                                            },
                                                            id);
                                                  });
                                                }
                                                if (documentSnapshot['value'] ==
                                                    0.5) {
                                                  String id =
                                                      documentSnapshot['docid'];
                                                  Provider.of<ManageData>(
                                                          context,
                                                          listen: false)
                                                      .deleteData(context, id);
                                                }
                                              },
                                              child: const Text('-'),
                                            ),
                                            const SizedBox(width: 20),
                                            Text(documentSnapshot['value']
                                                .toString()),
                                            const SizedBox(width: 20),
                                            ElevatedButton(
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                String id =
                                                    documentSnapshot['docid'];
                                                final user =
                                                    Provider.of<Userr?>(context,
                                                        listen: false);
                                                var postDocRef =
                                                    FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                                        .collection('myOrders')
                                                        .doc(user?.uid)
                                                        .collection('items')
                                                        .doc();
                                                Provider.of<ManageData>(context,
                                                        listen: false)
                                                    .UpdateCart(
                                                        context,
                                                        {
                                                          'value':
                                                              documentSnapshot[
                                                                      'value'] +
                                                                  0.5,
                                                          'price': documentSnapshot[
                                                                  'price'] +
                                                              (documentSnapshot[
                                                                      'ogprice'] /
                                                                  2),
                                                        },
                                                        id);
                                              },
                                              child: const Text('+'),
                                            ),
                                          ]),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            );
                          });
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag
                    // color: AppColors.blackColor,
                    ),
                title: Text(
                  'Your Orders',
                  // style: TextStyles.highlighterTwo,
                ),
                trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
              ),
            ]),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How to make that stream builder cart items scrollable by touching on it?

I tried using SingleChildScrollView but that only helps in extending the page down but not making the cart items scrollable by touching on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add NeverScrollablePhysics to the listview builder?

```
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
```